# SWFTools and events - creating internal link

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, pdf2swf

I'm using FlashPage to generate a flip page based on PDF. Basically we use swftools (pdf2swf) to convert each pdf page to a swf and display it in FlashPage.

To follow internal links, FlashPage recomends that we attach the following actions to the button:

```
on(rollOver, dragOver){
            _root.canflip=false; // flipping disabled
}
on(rollOut, dragOut, releaseOutside){
            _root.canflip=true; // flipping enabled
}

on(release){
            _root.canflip=true; // flipping enabled
            _root.gotoPage(4,true); // go to page
}
```

In swftools we can attach a function to an internal link using `-s internallinkfunction=<name>`

How can I attach those events like `on(release){}` to `internallinkfunction`

Also, there's an easy way to debug the swf generated by swftools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution.

I created a long post explaining how to solve it: http://www.zeletron.com.br/2012/06/reverse-engineering-swf-to-fix-limitation-in-swftools.html